# XSLT: Transforming Recursive and Repeatable Xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Receiving a recursive xml a legacy application like this

```
<ResponseXml>
    <AccountData>
    <AccountInformation>
     <AccountNumber>123465</AccountNumber>
     <BankCode>456</BankCode>
     <OwnerInformation>
      <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
      <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
     </OwnerInformation>
     <AccountInformation>
      <AccountNumber>78910</AccountNumber>
      <BankCode>123</BankCode>
      <OwnerInformation>
       <FirstName>My</FirstName>
       <LastName>Wife</LastName>
      </OwnerInformation>
     </AccountInformation>
    </AccountInformation>
   </AccountData>
   </ResponseXml>
```

It has to be formatted into:

```
<BillingInformation>
 <AccountNumber>123465</AccountNumber>
 <BankCode>456</BankCode>
</BillingInformation>
<ClientInfo>
 <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
 <LastName>Yadav</LastName>
</ClientInfo>
<BillingInformation2>
 <AccountNumber>78910</AccountNumber>
 <BankCode>123</BankCode>
</BillingInformation2>
<ClientInfo>
 <FirstName>My</FirstName>
 <LastName>Wife</LastName>
</ClientInfo>
```

Being new to XSLT transformation I am getting into multiple issues:

1. Excluding Child Elements while copying parent values.
2. And then copying excluded child elements under new root elements.

**Tried so far.**
Partial solution for the recursive part. It does not excludes root elements `<ResponseXml><AccountData>`

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AccountInformation">
    <BillingInformation>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='AccountInformation']"/>
    </BillingInformation>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountInformation"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AccountInformation/AccountInformation">
    <BillingInformation2>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </BillingInformation2>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have added my partial solution to handle recursive part of the xml. But i have no idea about excluding each child `<Owner>` element.

Comment: Do you think I approached this problem in a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the identity template then you have to **override** that template for any element that you want to act on. In this case if all you need is to remove the `ResponseXml` and `AccountData` elements then you just create an empty template for them both.

```
<xsl:template match="ResponseXml | AccountData">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

With that above line added to your XSL then it will not output those two elements.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about copying the child elements?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I missed the fact that this would not output the child elements. I've updated the answer to show how to remove the elements and continue processing the child elements.